# Replicate existing database live

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, testing, windows-server

New to db admin here and I have a question. My setup is Windows Server 2012 R2, MySQL, using MySQL Workbench.

I have `Database A` on `Server A`, how can I make an exact clone of this database (`Database B`) on `Server B`.

I realise I can export/import but that's not what I require. I need `Database B` to exactly mirror `Database A`, all changes made on `Database A` (i.e inserts, updates, deletes) should be reflected on `Database B` in real time. I only need to read from `Server A`, not write to it.

Is this possible?

`Server A` and `Server B` are different PCs (different IP addresses) but will have the same setup, so compatibility won't be an issue.

The reason I want to do this is for testing. Until now I have been exporting/importing the database daily, which works however there must be an easier/automated way that I am missing?

I have read up on database mirroring and cloning however I think I am way off the mark?

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: If you aren't going to change the data on B, then it sounds like you are looking for [asynchronous replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication.html). (Async? Yes, trust me for a moment). If you *are* going to change data on B, then, your question is unclear because "all changes ... should be reflected ... in real time."  If you change data on B, directly, then reflecting all changes from A becomes undefined (e.g.  delete row X on B, update row X on A, server B will not contain the updated value from A, since there was nothing on B to update).

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot yes it sounds like I am looking for asynchronous replication! I won't be changing the data on B, I updated my question accordingly. I only need the changes on A to be reflected on B. If you add an answer I'll accept - thanks!

Comment: Happy to help point you in the right direction, but it seems a little superfluous to post (essentially) "use replication" as an answer to the question "how do I replicate?"  MySQL replication is a stable technology, and the details on configuring it are in the documentation as noted, so I'm voting to close this question.  If you get stuck in the process, there are a number of existing Q&A here on the topic. If you encounter any issues that haven't been addressed on the site, feel free to post a new question on the specific issue.